# How to filter a table in angularjs based on different icons in a column?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

Let us say I have a table in angularjs having five columns. The first column of the table contains 3 different icons.

```
(1) glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-lock
(2) glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-book
(3) glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt
```

Now I want to filter this table based on the first columns icon.

Let us assume that there is a drop down or a textbox present above that column to filter. How can I do that ??

any help is appreciable Thanks!!!

[image]

Comment: Can you show the html code ?

Comment: suppose If I select lock icon all the rows having lock icon present should be displayed and others not

Comment: I ask html code to see how you define which icon should be display. The best way to do it is to not rely on icon but on controller data :)